# Intellij Error:Cannot build Artifact 'XXX:war exploded' because it is included into a circular dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

The project was working well before, but suddenly can not update war file in "target" directory.When I want to "Build Artifacts", error shows:
`Error:Cannot build Artifact 'XXX:war exploded' because it is included into a circular dependency`

What is the wrong with this?

the artifacts :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Gonna need to see your build file most likely to help.

Comment: @CollinD Do you mean pom.xml ?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The solution is to remove "MavenDemo:war" artifact and "MavenDemo:war exploded" artifact from the project, and rebuild the project、rebuild artifacts. set the deployment artifact from MavenDemo:war to MaterialManager:war.

I think the problem of this project is that the "MavenDemo:war" artifact and "MavenDemo:war exploded" artifact are repeated. So the solution is to remove them from the project.

1:

[image: 1]

2:

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

3:

[image: 4]

4:

[image: 5]

And then, Everytime after I make some update in my code, I can click "Run" Button to deploy the updated project to Tomcat successfully.

Hope it can help somebody else ~

Comment: Images will not be shown, please explain in detail what can we do step by step. thanks

Comment: Awesome, that was a pain. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

If you use Maven than just delete all artifacts and than right click on you project and select Maven -> Reimport

that works for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gradle you can

1. You can delete your artifacts in Project Structure.
2. Then change *Group* or *Version* in build file then build gradle and voilia you got new artifacts which you can use in your web-app.
3. Actually, if you don't want to change its group or version you can do the same job with rename it back.

Answer (score 0):

Decision is:
open folder .idea, there you'll find your artifacts (.idea/artifacts), keep one of them that you need, another delete.